# Change AD user attributes of users in group

Tags: powershell

I copied and pasted together this script that looks at all the member in a certain group, and then changes all of their company names. I would now like to expand this script to be able to ask for which attribute of the users you want to change.

```
Clear-Host

$GPNAME = Read-Host 'Provide the Group Name here'
#$whatwhat = Read-Host 'Which Attribute do you want to change | Put a - infront'
$attrib = Read-Host 'Give new company name here' #This should later change to "Give new info of Attribute you want to change"

$description = "-description"
$offeece = "-office"
$department = "-department"
$company = "-company"

$Userslist = Get-ADGroupMember $GPNAME

ForEach($User in $Userslist)
{
$user1 = $User.name
#Write-Host $user1
get-aduser -filter { name -eq $User1 } | set-aduser -company $attrib
}
```

at the end of the script i would like to change the -company with $whatwhat.
I have tried it, but no matter how, with the - or without, with ' and " around the - or the $whatwhat, it keeps on giving me this error.

```
Set-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'newly'
```

can anyone assist my to expand this script a little bit by giving the user options to choose from, or allowing him/her to type: company or description or office

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `invoke-expression` cmdlet

```
$cmd="get-aduser -filter { name -eq $User1 } | set-aduser $whatwhat $attrib -whatif"
invoke-expression $cmd
```

test :

```
PS>$what=read-host "attribute to change :"  attribute to change ::
company              
PS>$c="set-aduser test -$what 'testcpny' -whatif"         
PS>iex $c
WhatIf : Opération « Set » en cours sur la cible « CN=TEST,CN=Users,DC=....,DC=com ».
```

Comment: tried that now, then it gies me the same error, could you perhaps explain if i need to modify any other line above the $cmd

Comment: normaly no, i'll put a complete test case in my answer

Comment: Excellent stuff. I had to remove the -whatif, tested and working like a charm. Asking for the Group to look through, asks for the attribute to change and then changes it gracefully :)